# What is the difference between app.doScript and $.evalFile?

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript, indesign-server

The only difference I have found so far: If a script that is run by `app.doScript` returns an error, the file and line number of the error are overridden by the file and line number of the `app.doScript` call.

Are there any other differences I should know about?

Here's sample code that demonstrates the above difference:

First run InDesign:

```
c:
cd "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe InDesign CS6 Server x64"
InDesignServer.com -port 12345
pause
```

Next create a batch file to run a script:

```
c:
cd "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe InDesign CS6 Server x64"
sampleclient -host localhost:12345 -server "C:/doscript_vs_evalfile/call_doScript.jsx"
pause
```

This is "call_doScript.jsx", which will call app.doScript.

```
try {
    app.doScript(new File("/c/doscript_vs_evalfile/called_by_doScript.jsx"));
    "Success";
}
catch (e) {
    var sError = "Encountered " + e.name + " #" + e.number + " at line " + e.line + " of file " + e.fileName + "\n" + e.message;
    app.consoleout(sError);
    sError;
}
```

This is "called_by_doScript.jsx", which is called by the previous script:

```
app.consoleout("Running called_by_doScript.jsx");
// Produce error
var a = b;
```

Run the batch file and this is the result:

```
02/25/13 13:30:03 INFO  [javascript] Executing File: C:\doscript_vs_evalfile\call_doScript.jsx
02/25/13 13:30:03 INFO  [javascript] Executing File: C:\doscript_vs_evalfile\called_by_doScript.jsx
02/25/13 13:30:03 INFO  [script] Running called_by_doScript.jsx
02/25/13 13:30:03 INFO  [script] Encountered ReferenceError #2 at line 2 of file /c/doscript_vs_evalfile/call_doScript.jsx
b is undefined
```

Notice that the error above is incorrect. The error was caused by line 3 of called_by_doScript, not line 2 of call_doScript.

Now modify the scripts to use $.evalFile, and we get this result:

```
02/25/13 13:32:39 INFO  [javascript] Executing File: C:\doscript_vs_evalfile\call_evalFile.jsx
02/25/13 13:32:39 INFO  [script] Running called_by_evalFile.jsx
02/25/13 13:32:39 INFO  [script] Encountered ReferenceError #2 at line 3 of file /c/doscript_vs_evalfile/called_by_evalFile.jsx
b is undefined
```

Notice that the error is now reported at the correct location.

---

**Edit:**

I found sparse documentation. It doesn't really answer my question, but it does describe different optional parameters.

**doScript:** [Adobe InDesign CS6 Scripting Guide: JavaScript](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/documentation.html) ([direct link](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/scripting/InDesign_ScriptingGuide_JS.pdf))
See page 16, "Using the doScript Method"

**evalFile:** [Javascript Tools Guide: Adobe Creative Suite 5](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/indesign/pdfs/JavaScriptToolsGuide_CS5.pdf)
See page 219

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I would venture that with app.doscript, you can run js files as well as vbs files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$.evalFile is an ExtendScript feature while app.doScript is implemented by InDesign.

$.evalFile does

- maintain the $.stack
- consider $.includePath
- work in other target applications

app.doScript can

- pass arguments
- change the language, e.g. AppleScript
- use #targetengine to address other sessions
- modify the undo/transaction mode as far as supported

but ...

- nested doScript calls overwrite arguments
- in a complicated setup I had trouble to debug after passing more than 12 arguments.
- single stepping across doScript is trouble

Also, as you found, error handling differs. Keep an eye on exceptions ...

Comment: Can anyone of these be used to access a js-file remotely on a web-server? i.e. 'http://mywebsite/script.js'?

Comment: @CarlPapworth You can use `app.doScript` to execute an AppleScript to run a `do shell script` to execute a `curl` command. You'll have to ensure quotes are escaped properly but it does work. Sadly, this is the only way I've found to do this in ExtendScript.